# portlet level to page level redirection from @RenderMapping method

Tags: java, spring, jsp, liferay, portlet

When the page is loading I need to redirect to another page in controller level.
I have tried a lot. But I could not be able to find a way. So as a workaround in controller  level I put a flag variable to 'ModelMap' and in 'JSP' and 'JS' level I read that and redirect using javascript.

```
window.location
```

I feel this is not a better way. Following "getConfirmationPage" is the method that is executing in loading the page.

Also I tried

```
response.sendRedirect("https://stackoverflow.com/?p=1");
```

But that one also not worked fine for me.

Can anyone suggest best practice.
I use spring4/liferay 6.2.4/portlet/JSP as technology in my project. This is portlet related question.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("VIEW")
public class ConfirmationController extends AbstractControllerTemplate {


@RenderMapping
public ModelAndView getConfirmationPage(
        RenderRequest req,
        PortletSession session) {
  ModelMap mm = new ModelMap();
 //conditionally need to redirect to different liferay page not portlet
  return new ModelAndView("confirmation", mm);
}
```

edited
**This is my logic**
my incoming URL is like this https://stackoverflow.com/?p=2 but logically p=2 is invalid for him. So what I try to do is I redirect him to p=1

```
https://stackoverflow.com/?p=1
```

Comment: *"When the page is loading I need to redirect to another page in controller level"* Can you elaborate on this? Do you need an HTTP-level redirect? Under which circumstances? Or just display different HTML content in your portlet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use bellow code line to solve your problem. Variable response should be type of PortletResponse/ResourceResponse.

```
HttpServletResponse res =PortalUtil.getHttpServletResponse(response)
```

Here is a sample code segment to elaborate your requirement.

```
    try{

            HttpServletResponse res = PortalUtil.getHttpServletResponse(response);
            String url = PortalUtil.getCurrentCompleteURL(PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest( req ) );
            String param1=getParamValue(url,"p");//logic here to return param from URL

            if(param1!=null && param1.trim().length()>0){
                requestPageNumber=Integer.parseInt(param1);
            }

            if(requestPageNumber<=uiState.getPageNunmber())//valid
            {}
            else//invalid
            {
                res.sendRedirect( "/proposerdetails?p="+uiState.getPageNunmber() );
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Happy coding !!!!